# how to write test case for ngdialog preclosecallback - jasmine karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
how to write unit test case for ngdialog preclosecallback event 

how to write test case for ngdialog
```

dialog = ngDialog.openConfirm({
                                    scope: scope,
     preCloseCallback:function() {
                                        $rootScope.myvariable= false;
                                    }
    });

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are curious how to test the callback function. Just remember that you have access to it as an argument passed into the method you are spying on. Since you have a handle to it, you can execute it, and test it like any other method you would test.

You should be able to start with the following, though if it were me, I'd probably split it up into multiple tests...

```
it('should call ngDiag.openConfirm()', inject(function($rootScope, ngDialog) {
  // Arrange
  var expectedScope = getExpectedScope();
  $rootScope.myvariable = true;
  spyOn(ngDialog, 'openConfirm')

  // Act
  scope.executeCodeOrWhateverTriggersItToRun();

  // Assert
  expect(ngDialog.openConfirm.calls.count()).toBe(1);

  var args = ngDialog.openConfirm.calls.argsFor(0);
  expect(args).not.toBe(null);
  expect(args.length).toBe(1);

  var options = args[0];
  expect(options.scope).toBe(expectedScope);
  expect(typeof options.preCloseCallback).toBe('function');

  options.preCloseCallback()
  expect($rootScope.myvariable).toBe(false);
}));
```